# I am learning coding theory in discrete mathematics, can someone illustrate an example of an $alphabet$, code and codeword please?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, coding-theory

I have that the following definitions;

1. An $alphabet$ $\sum$ is a set of symbols.
2. A code $y$ over $\sum$ is a collection of sequences of symbols.
3. The members of $y$ are called codewords.

Could you illustrate an example of an $alphabet$, code and codeword and how they are all linked together please?

Comment: This question seems a little broad. Which part of the definitions do you not understand?

Comment: Mostly the second definition, what does it mean by a collection of sequences of symbols?

Comment: Say $\Sigma=\{a,b,c,...,z\}$, then a code is a set of all valid English words according to Oxford English Dictionary, (so we interpret the word math as sequence $(m,a,t,h)$), and the codewords are simply entries of the dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An *alphabet* $\Sigma$ is a nonempty set of symbols (called *letters*).  For example, the alphabet $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$ contains the letters $0$ and $1$.

A *codeword* (or a *word*) is a list of letters chosen from an alphabet.  We usually express codewords as concatenations of letters.  For example, some possible codewords over $\Sigma=\{0,1\}$ are $0$, $10$, $11$, and $101$.  Note that concatenation is usually non-commutative.  That is, the codeword $10$ is usually considered as different from the codeword $01$.

A *code* is a set of codewords.  For example, $y=\{0,10,11,101\}$ is a code.

Comment: @Joel_Reyes_Noche So using the the second definition I have written above and the example you gave, would the sequence of symbols refer to the codewords 0, 10, 11 and 101.

Comment: Yes.  Although you might think of a sequence of letters as something like $0,1,1$, I understand that in coding theory this is usually written as $011$.

Comment: Note that an alphabet could be infinite (that is, be composed of an infinite number of letters) and a code could also be infinite (that is, be composed of an infinite number of codewords).

Comment: In your example is $y$ considered to be a binary code because it is only made  up of the letters 0 and 1. Also what is the distance between the codewords 10 and 11?

Comment: Yes, and a codeword of $101$ has a length of 3.  Depending on how you define it, it may even be possible to have a word of length 0 (the empty word, usually represented by the symbol $\epsilon$).

Comment: Yes, $y$ is a binary code because its alphabet is binary (consists of two letters).

Comment: Thanks. Finally what is the distance between the codewords 10 and 11?

Comment: I recommend that you ask new questions in a new comment instead of changing your previous comment.  People reading the comments won't understand my answers because you changed your questions.

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance), "In information theory, the Hamming distance between two strings of equal length is the number of positions at which the corresponding symbols are different."  Thus, the codewords $10$ and $11$ have a Hamming distance of 1 (because they differ in only one position: the second).